# String exact and potential matches

Tags: java

I'm implementing a join between JSONs objects extracted from a company's normalized database and from unstructured data from Twitter, based on the name and location fields. For clarification, this join is done with MapReduce, so there is no other way than to implement manually the join condition.
The obvious implementation is to concatenate and compare these fields with Java String.equals method.  Consider these two JSONs, the first extracted from the normalized data and the second from Twitter:

```
{"location":"Rio de Janeiro - Brasil","name":"Joao Paulo Forny "}
{"location":"RiodeJaneiro;Brasil","name":"JoaoPaulo-Forny!"}
```

The join condition below can find matches between same names and location that contains the same letters in the same order due to the use of a regex to eliminate all spaces and other chars than letters.

```
obj1.getJoinKey().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "")
.equals(ob2.getJoinKey().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", ""))
```

As Twitter data is not normalized, the fields can contain no information or only pieces of information or even information that is not related to the specific field, so there are cases that is impossible to compute anything. However, there are cases that is possible to find potential matches, e.g., the location may contain only city, the name may not have all of the middle names or last name, also the words can be the same but out of order.

```
{"location":"Rio de Janeiro - Brasil","name":"Joao Paulo Forny de Melo"} 
{"location":"Rio de Janeiro","name":"Joao Paulo Forny de Melo"}

{"location":"Rio de Janeiro - Brasil","name":"Joao Paulo Forny de Melo"} 
{"location":"Rio de Janeiro - Brasil","name":"Joao Forny"}

{"location":"Rio de Janeiro - Brasil","name":"Joao Paulo Forny de Melo"}
{"location":"Brasil - Rio de Janeiro","name":"Joao Paulo Forny de Melo"}
```

The question is, what solutions can be used to find potential matches based on the three conditions described above?

Comment: You might want to look at something like lucene for this.

Comment: You could always calculate their [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which is a measure of the "distance" between two Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the three specific examples that you've given:

1. *One location contains only city; the other contains city and state/country.*  In this case, you can break the string up into two parts, separated by any non-alphanumeric, non-whitespace character, and normalize spacing (perhaps by removing it).  For example, "Brasil;Rio de Janiero" would become "Brasil" and "RiodeJaniero".  Then you can test whether at least one substring from one of the locations matches one of the substrings from one of the other locations.  In order to prevent just matching the country, you could conceivably create a list of all the countries and exclude those matches.  There are only a couple hundred countries, although I'm sure there are several alternate spellings for many of them depending on language.  But if you do not do that, you will end up matching, say, "Sao Paulo - Brasil" and "Rio de Janiero - Brasil".
2. *One name may not have a middle or last name.*  I tend to think that you'd have to have at least a first and last name in order to match at all.  Imagine how many Joaos there are in Brazil or in Portugal.  So again in this case, break the strings up into substrings, and make sure that at least two parts match each other.  You'll need another exclusion list, though, with things like "von" and "de" and "O'" and so forth in it.
3. *Order of state and country is reversed.*  This is just a special case of #1 above.  You'll have both substrings matching rather than just one.

Hopefully that helps.  I'm not sure that it's a full solution, but hopefully at least it can lead you on the way to a full solution.